# License key not showing up in MATLAB command prompt

Tags: matlab

I created a MathWorks account a few days ago and it said that I have to enter a license key to activate MATLAB (like it always does). It told me that I can get my license key by entering `license` into the command prompt, so I did, and i just got this:

```
ans =

  0x0 empty char array
```

I have looked up how to solve this **many** times! Can somebody help me obtain my license key correctly?

Comment: That's weird! What Matlab version and OS are you running on?

Comment: Have you registered your MATLAB installation? If not, it won't know the key (and you probably won't be able to use it for very long unless it is a really old version)

Comment: Thanks, @max! I was using the online version by mistake!